# Table was not found in location US - BigQuery INSERT

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a stored procedure in BigQuery where I do some transformations and data inserts and deletes.

I have one query in my procedure which, for some reason, fails with:

> Not found: Table
> rdg-datawarehouse:Amazon_Raw._metadata_order_items was not
> found in location US at
> [rdg-datawarehouse.Amazon.update_orders:141:1]

```
insert into `rdg-datawarehouse.Amazon_Raw._metadata_order_items` (OrderId, PurchaseDate, processed_flag)
select distinct 
    src.OrderId, 
    src.PurchaseDate, 
    0 as processed_bit
from `rdg-datawarehouse.Amazon_Raw.Orders` src
  inner join `last_updated_orders` tmp
    on src.OrderId = tmp.OrderId 
    and src.LastUpdateDate = tmp.LastUpdateDate
    and src.import_timestamp = tmp.last_import_timestamp
  left join `rdg-datawarehouse.Amazon_Raw._metadata_order_items` mit
    on tmp.OrderId = mit.OrderId
  where coalesce(mit.OrderId, 1) = 1;
```

The `last_updated_orders` table is a temporary table defined previously in the procedure.

```
create temp table `last_updated_orders` (OrderId STRING, LastUpdateDate TIMESTAMP, last_import_timestamp TIMESTAMP)
as
select ...
```

I have checked both datasets and tables, and they are all stored in the US.

I have even tried forcing the query session to run in the US, by going to More -> Query Settings and setting the Data Location as "US".

[image]

But, unfortunately nothing has worked. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: According to [public doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages) *`404 NotFound error` returns when you refer to a resource (a dataset, a table, or a job) that doesn't exist. This can also occur when using table decorators to refer to deleted tables that have recently been streamed to*.If you have a support plan for your project it's better to raise a ticket with [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) so that you can have a proper Root Cause Analysis.Or you can also create a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Also make sure you are mentioning the dataset/table’s name properly in your query before contacting any support.